# Question on group action of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ on a regular hexagon

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-actions

I was working with $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ acting on a regular hexagon where $\bar{n}$ acts as rotation by $2n\pi/3,$ clockwise. By labeling the vertices (I started with $1$ at the top left corner going clockwise) of the hexagon $1,2,3,4,5,6$ we have the homomorphism $\alpha: \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow S_6$ such that $$\bar{0},\bar{3}\mapsto (1)$$
$$\bar{1},\bar{4}\mapsto (1\:2\:3\:4\:5\:6)$$
$$\bar{2},\bar{5}\mapsto (1\:3\:5)(\:2\:4\:6)$$

Now, let $O$ be the set of opposite vertices i.e. $O=\{\{1,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,6\}\}.$ Then we have the homomorphism $\beta: \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow S_O$ such that
$$\bar{0},\bar{3}\mapsto\{\{1,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,6\}\}$$
$$\bar{1},\bar{4}\mapsto\{\{2,5\},\{3,6\},\{1,4\}\}$$ 
$$\bar{2},\bar{5}\mapsto\{\{3,6\},\{1,4\},\{2,5\}\}$$

Is this correct?

To clear any ambiguity the following is how I labeled my hexagon:
[image]

Comment: $\beta$ maps equivalence classes into sets, what's the operation in such set?? i.e., how is the morphism defined?? in the map $\alpha$ it is clear what it should be though

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find i.e. the action of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ on $O.$

Comment: @CristianBaeza The operation is stated in the first sentence.

Comment: Oh, ok, since you, in a sense, redefined the set $O$ I thought there could have been a different operation. In such case, it is just as you have it, $\beta$ fixes $O$, as you can see you get each time the same elements. Cheers

Comment: I might be being silly, but isn’t it true that $\bar{1}\mapsto (1\,3\,5)(2\,4\,6)$? Since a rotation by $2\pi/3$ applied three times is $2\pi$, the corresponding permutation should have order three.

Comment: @SantanaAfton yeah that's what I had initially, but in that case what would $\bar{2}$ map to? Which is why I changed it to how I have it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but your calculations are off.

With your current labeling, the map $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\to S_6$ you've defined has the following images. I write '$e$' to be the identity permutation.

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\bar{0} & \mapsto \text{ rotation by 0 } & = e \\
\bar{1} & \mapsto \text{ rotation by }\frac{2\pi}{3} & = (135)(246) \\
\bar{2} & \mapsto \text{ rotation by }\frac{4\pi}{3} & = (153)(264) \\
\bar{3} & \mapsto \text{ rotation by }2\pi & = e \\
\bar{4} & \mapsto \text{ rotation by }\frac{8\pi}{3}=2\pi + \frac{2\pi}{3} & = (135)(246) \\
\bar{5} & \mapsto \text{ rotation by }\frac{10\pi}{3} = 2\pi + \frac{4\pi}{3} & = (153)(264) \\
\end{array}$$

With this, can you find the images of each $\bar{n}$ for the map $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\to S_O$?

Comment: As an exercise, you should attempt to do this same problem for the maps $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \to S_6$ by $\bar{n}\mapsto$ rotation by $\frac{2n\pi}{6}$ and by $\bar{n}\mapsto$ rotation by $n\pi$.

Comment: Thanks. Quick questions. For $\bar{2}$ how did you get $(153)(264)$? Is it always the case that the "last" permutation is the inverse of the prior permutation?

Comment: @TomásPalamás A rotation by $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ is two applications of a rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, i.e. it will be $[(135)(246)]^2$. You can also look at where vertices go under a two-thirds rotation clockwise to see this.

Comment: I see it now. I was thinking about it differently. Also, kinda off topic, in case I wanted to verify that the group action is well defined for $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ on the regular hexagon, how would I go about it?

Comment: Well, what does it mean for a group action to be well-defined?

Comment: That if two equivalent elements in the first group map to the same element in the second group. So in this case would it be that for $\phi: \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow D_6$, we want to show that if $\bar{n}=\bar{m}$ then $\phi(\bar{n})=\phi(\bar{m})$?

Comment: That’s exactly right! You should unwind the definition of $\bar{n}$ a bit and think about the trick I did for finding the image of $\bar{4}$ and $\bar{5}$.

Comment: I sure will! Last question. So would the image of $\bar{2}$ for $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow S_O$ be $\{\{5,2\},\{6,3\},\{1,4\}\}$?

Comment: @TomásPalamás Yup, that’s correct. Though you would write it as $(~\dots~)$ since the image is a permutation, not a set.